# Java hashmap issue

Tags: java, hashmap

Any ideas why following line has the related error message? Thanks.

**Code**

```
Map<int,boolean> buffer = new HashMap<int, boolean>();
```

**Error Message**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType
```

Comment: You cannot use primitive types in Maps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
Map<Integer,Boolean> buffer = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

You cannot use primitive types with genericity.

You will need to use Wrapper classes for them.

Comment: Thanks Pritam  and Yassin! Vote up and mark your reply as answer.